# Netflix Zuul stop redirecting / enable reverse-proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have following Zuul configuration. Also I have disabled Eureka since I have service discovery in place.

```
server:
   port: 7777


ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: false


zuul:
  prefix: /api
  routes:
    yourService:
      path: /newpath/**
      serviceId: yourService


yourService:
  ribbon:
    listOfServers: localhost:8080/rest
```

Now when I hit `localhost:7777/api/newpath` Zuul does a 302 redirection rather than reverse-proxying transparently. Please advise how to stop this redirection and get Zuul to reverse-proxy transparently.

Comment: Are you sure that zuul is the one sending 302 and not your service?

Comment: Yes. I don't have auth or any other configurations. So it must be Zuul

Comment: Zuul does not do any redirecting.

Comment: @Fahim Farook - Did you find any solution? i too need this..

Answer (score 2):

Try it with trailing slash as it's in the rule:

http://localhost:7777/api/newpath/